# How do you horizontal align submit button?

Tags: html, css

How do you make this search button to center align horizontally?

[image: This is how it looks like]

```
input.search {
    width: 7em; height: 3em;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #777777;
}
```

Comment: You need to change the **button's container**'s style, not the button style. you need to change the container to `text-align:center`

Comment: Please post the code which has the problem: The button with the container and the related CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inputs by default use the `display:inline;` style, which means that the parent element would need to have `text-align:center;` like this:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #404040;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Or alternatively, you can change the display type of the button/input to `display:block;` and use auto margins like this:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #404040;
  padding: 5px;
}
.submit {
  display:block;
  width: 100px; /* note that display block will go full width unless you specify otherwise */
  text-align:center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

is this what you need ?

```css
.full-width {
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  background:#404040;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
  <input type="button" value="search" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use center tag

```html
<center>
<input type="button" value="search"/>
</center>
```

Comment: Whilst some browser may still support this, the `<center>` tag was [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) in HTML5. Hope this doesn't come across as weird, maybe add that to your answer, and I can remove it from the comments?